# Image Rename Zip And Download codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

> Currently the zip is downloading and the images within the zip are off the names that are stored on the server  i need to rename them 
>   I have 3 images on the server i need to download the images but before adding files to zip i need to  rename them

```
public function downimages(){
```

$this->_check(); *// session checker*

$this->load->helper('download');

$this->load->library('zip');

$idm=$this->uri->segment(3);

$ab=$this->adminmod->downimg($idm);

$down=explode('-/,-', $ab[0]->director);  *//gets the directory stores in array*

$fname=explode('-/,-', $ab[0]->file_oname); *//gets the file names stores in array*

foreach ($down as $key =>$value){

$name = $fname[$key];     *// this is where the name is stored need to use this* to   rename
$data = "./"($value);

$this->zip->read_file($data);    *//adds the images to zip archive*
}

$this->zip->download($idm.'.zip'); *//downloads the zip fles*

// redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}

> My server image names are like  xfasf.jpg 2) sadweq.jpg  3)wqweq.jpg
>    my actual file names are  image1.jpg  2)blue.jpg 3)red.jpg  whcih comes from $name

How do i go about this?

**Solution Was Quite Easy**

Solved IT at the `$this->zip->read_file($data);` 
I just put the $name like this
 `$this->zip->read_file($data,$name);` 
now the files get renamed before they get zipped and then downloaded

Comment: Solved IT  at the `$this->zip->read_file($data);` i jsut put the $name  like this `$this->zip->read_file($data,$name);` now the files get renamed before they get downloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved IT  at the `$this->zip->read_file($data);` i jsut put the $name  like this `$this->zip->read_file($data,$name);` now the files get renamed before they get downloaded